# @Transactional + @Retryable: are there any potential problems?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, transactional

I have these annotations on a method in a spring project. At first sight it works as expected but is there any problems with that annotation as there is not a lot documentation about these 2 working together. The main goal is when we have a serializable access problem to retry the transaction 3 times.

```
  @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
  @Retryable(maxAttempts = 3, include = JpaSystemException.class)
  public MyClassSecond myUpdatingMethod(final MyClassFirst arg1)
```

Comment: elmehdi at least read the question before stating such things, because your statement will spoil the question...

Comment: i did , the answer of the question i mention resume the downside of using both and how they work so you can expect potential problems, if you looking for specific problem , please update your question